# How to use the chrome.history.search API for Google Chrome browser Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a simple chrome extension. Trying to utilize a

```
chrome.history.search("", function(results) {
        alert(results);
});
```

If search is empty it will search everything as per documentation.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#type-HistoryItem
My chrome managed to reach to this particular line of code. However in the Chrome extension tab `chrome://extensions/ > Developer Mode > Load Unpacked`  I'm getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of history.search(object query, function callback): No matching signature.
```

And if I press F12, to activate developers tool I see the following warnings, 36 of the same warnings.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of history.search(object query, function callback): No matching signature.
```

My `manifest.json` is already asking for access to history

```
 "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "history"
   ]
```

**Any pointer of what went wrong?**

Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: See the documentation and usage examples for chrome.history.search, the first parameter is an object, not a string. Also you can't use alert to display the results because it's a nested object so you'll need to use console.log or use devtools breakpoints.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried:  `chrome.history.search({"query":""}, ` or `chrome.history.search({""}, ` those also didn't work.

Comment: Programming doesn't work like this. Please actually read the documentation. The parameter name is `text`, not `query`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the empty string as an object `{text: ""}`

```
chrome.history.search({text: ""}, function(results) {
        alert(results);
});
```